# Kie Workbench, Guided Rule, Creating objects in Rules

Tags: java, drools, drools-guvnor, kie-workbench

I am a novice in Drools and Kie Workbench so please bear with me. I am having trouble deciding on the best way to write the 'THEN' part of a guided rule. My issue is as follows:

Rule: If a client has a specific asset class, then generate and add a task list to off board the client. For example:

```
when
    clientOffBoard : ClientOffBoard( activity == Activity.PREVENT_TRADE && , client.assetClass == AssetClass.ETD )
```

In the THEN part, I need to do something like this:

```
then
    Task task1 = new Task();
    task1.setDescription( "Remove the client from system A" );
    insertLogical( task1 );
    clientOffBoard.addTask( task1 );
    Task task2 = new Task();
    task1.setDescription( "Notify Person B" );
    insertLogical( task2 );
    clientOffBoard.addTask( task2 );
    ...
```

My question is around the 'THEN' part and the Task objects. BA's should be able to create tasks as and when they need to. The Task object is just a container object with a "String description" field for now. Would the BA's need to create these up front or can they create them in the Guided Rule as I have done above?

Please note that new tasks may be created at any time by BAs using the Kie workbench and there many be thousands of Clients sharing the same tasks. The Tasklist for each clientOffBoard object may have 0-many tasks. What would be the best way to handle this in the workbench. Any advice would be appreciated.

My current setup involves creating a JAR file with my 'Facts', I.e. all the above classes but in the actual execution, the facts may be assigned values, I.e. creating a new Task object with a specific description, and then inserting this task to the clientOffBoard task list.

I hope this makes sense.

Thanks

Comment: Surely you don't want to let the BA's fumble around with these incantations? Some static method with two parameters (ClientOffBoard, String) is indicated. --   You write "sharing the same tasks", but you are using new to create a distinct new object? This doesn't make sense. -- What should happen due to the Task objects in WM? -- You cannot have objects (facts are objects) in a jar file. --  According to your snippet, the Engine is not aware of the added Tasks in the client's list. This may or may not be a problem.

Comment: Hi Laune,

Thanks for your comment, as mentioned, I am a newbie in Drools :)
What would you suggest be the best way to approach my problem? My requirements are as follows:

1. New 'Task' types can be created at any time.
2. For certain asset classes, specific tasks should be assigned to the clientOffBoard object.

For part 1 above, do I need to create these as facts up front rather than in the 'THEN' part of the rule?
For part 2 above, are you indicating that I should be calling a static method to do this?

Comment: part1: Anybody can use any string to define a new task instance? How could you create them "up front"? What does "sharing the same tasks" really mean? part2: You can let the BAs write 4 statements each for each new task, but they'll hate you. (I would.)

Comment: Let me clarify my requirements further. There will be several task lists. All these task lists should be editable (removal and adding of new tasks). Rules can be created/edited. To start with I need to create a task list. I then need to create a rule for example which says, if the asset class for a ClientOffBoard object is ETD, then set this taskList on it. The ClientOffBoard objects will then be loaded and the rule fired, setting this task list. How would I go about implementing this in Kie Workbench? Can it be done solely in the workbench and is it maintainable solely here?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you need a (modifiable) task list set. This should give you a set of Java objects - one per TaskList:

```
<TaskListSet>
   <TaskList id="use for ETD">
     <Task>Remove the client from system A</Task>
     <Task>Notify Person B</Task>
   </TaskList>
   <TaskList id="use for FOO">
     ...
   ...
</TaskListSet>
```

You cannot expect to provide the KieWorkbench to help you with this simple editing task. You could use an XML editor, or define another text format, etc.

The rule author would simply select the appropriate TaskList by its id and write

```
then
  clientOffBoard.setTaskList( "use for ETD" );
end
```

Perhaps individual tasks need to be inserted as facts (as you have it in your Q) but this is a technical detail.